# Python MemoryView '.cast()' function from network big endian format to little-endian

Tags: python, numpy, sockets, memoryview

I am reading data from a socket (UDP), which will obviously be using network format (always big-endian according to IETF RFC 1700), modifying some parameters, and then re-transmitting it on another socket. To avoid making lots of copies of the bytearray (data is coming in very frequently) I have been using a memoryview object, and passing that between the functions so the data is modified in-place:

```py
full_msg, addr = in_port.recvfrom(4096)
data = memoryview(full_msg)
if data:
    msg_id = data[:4]
    if msg_id == b'QRT1':
        Controller.QuaternionMsg.process(data)
    elif msg_id == b'QRT2':
        #etc
```

The data I am processing is a series of 4D vector floats, so the easiest way to read them is just to cast  the memory view object so it reads them as floats:

```py
>>> msg_data = data[4:].cast('f')
>>> msg_data[0]
0.12345
```

However, because the native byte-order on my PC is intel (little-endian), these are being read wrong. I tried using a similar syntax to the struct module but this isn't supported:

```py
>>> msg_data = data[4:].cast('!f')
ValueError: memoryview: destination format must be a native single character format prefixed with an optional '@'
```

Is there a way to force the memoryview object to read this in a particular byteorder? I know that I could use the struct module and make copies but I am trying to avoid that if possible.

---

### Another Option

I am also looking at numpy as an option, but I'm worried about any additional overhead that might bring. If I used:

```python
network_float = np.dtype(float)
network_float = network_float.newbyteorder('>')
data = np.frombuffer(full_msg,dtype=network_float, offset=4) #maybe not writeable?
```

would this allow me to do the same thing with not much extra overhead or does np.frombuffer make a copy if it's not pointed at an existing numpy array?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've got the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just went with the copying method using the struct module and 'readinto' etc. Not as efficient as I'd hoped, but was good enough that it didn't cause me a performance bottle-neck.

It would be nice if this could be improved though.